# Custom setter behaving like default one

Tags: c#, setter

I have a property in a model which had custom Getter, with no Setter. Now I need to make possible to set the value to Percent property. The problem is, there is a lot of logic connected to this property and I would like to avoid changing other code, than in this property.

I want to set the value directly to the Percent property, not some private field. Basically, same thing as default getter and setter. Is it possible to achieve it with custom setter?

I would love to do something like this:

```
public decimal Percent
{
    get { return Count / Total }
    set { this.Percent = value }
}
```

EDIT: some more background. In the model i have several properties representing numeric operations like Count, Sum, Total, Deviation etc. Most of the properties are calculated in SQL query and directly filled. All of the properties have default getter and setter. Only the Percent property is not loaded from db, because it calculates it's value based on previously filled Count and Total properties.

The model is used in List (List.. ) and some of the items will have the Percent property calculated differently than others with default Count / Total, that's why I need to implement set option to the property. So I want to set it's value like

```
private void CalculatePercents(List<StatisticOperations> Stats)
{
    // I have a way to get exactly the index I need and the calculation of 
    // the percent value (30), it just isn't necessary here, so for 
    // illustration:

    Stats[15].Percent = 30;
}
```

Types doesn't matter, let's say it's all decimal.

Comment: whats is the type of `Count` & `Total`?

Comment: If you want to save the value somewhere you will need a private property.  I guess you could write to and read from a DB in the getter and setter -- but I doubt that is what you mean by other than a private property -- why is it you don't want a private property?

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I think, independently what that is, this operation will return `double`

Comment: Usually, in situation when property returns something calculated, and is read only, you would add a method `void SetPercent(decimal percent)`

Comment: The type doesn't really matter, let's say percent, count and total are all decimal, or double.. It won't save anywhere, it loads values from db, but this property is just for display

Answer (score 1):

If you need a derived/calculated property with a setter, you can apply the reverse of getter:

```
public decimal Percent
{
    get => (decimal)Count / Total;
    set => Count = (int)(Total * value);
}
```

*assuming `Count` and `Total` are both `int`*